# useRef([]) with dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a component with several div elements.
By adding a ?goto= parameter to the url I want to scroll the the relevant element. I now solved that with `const itemsRef = useRef([]);`.
My main concern now is if that's the right and performance efficient approach with `itemsRef.current[element.id] = el`. element.id will be unique for each element.

I also found packages such as: https://github.com/Macil/react-multi-ref

But I don't see the disadvantage of my approach yet.

Here you can find my **current solution in action**: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolltoref-w5i7m?file=/src/Element.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

const blueprint = [
  {
    id: "3mD59WO",
    name: "AUDITORIUM",
    position: 0,
    rooms: [
      {
        id: "zR8Qgpj",
        name: "Audimax",
        subtitle: null,
        details: null,
        position: 0,
        elements: [
          {
            id: "1jLv04W",
            position: 0,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          },
          {
            id: "1jLv12W",
            position: 1,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "4mDd9WO",
    name: "FOYER",
    position: 1,
    rooms: [
      {
        id: "4R8Qgpj",
        name: "Speakers Table",
        subtitle: null,
        details: null,
        position: 0,
        elements: [
          {
            id: "2jLv04W",
            position: 0,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          },
          {
            id: "2jLv12W",
            position: 1,
            type: "daily",
            element: "listing_large",
            properties: {
              meetingId: null,
              capacity: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function Query() {
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);
  const [currentRef, setCurrentRef] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollToRef = ref => {
      window.scrollTo(0, ref.offsetTop);
    };

    const goto = "1jLv12W"; // This will become an URL parameter ?goto=:someID in the final version
    const ref = itemsRef.current[goto];
    setCurrentRef(ref); // This is needed to change the className to highlight
    scrollToRef(ref); // Here I assign the ref and the component should scroll to that ref
  }, []);

  return (
    <div key="element">
      {blueprint.map(floor => (
        <div key={floor.id} style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
          Floor: {floor.name} <br />
          <br />
          {floor.rooms.map(room => (
            <div key={room.id}>
              Room Name: {room.name}
              <br />
              {room.elements.map(element => (
                <div
                  ref={el => (itemsRef.current[element.id] = el)}
                  className={clsx({
                    highlight:
                      currentRef && currentRef === itemsRef.current[element.id]
                  })}
                  key={element.id}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "green", marginTop: 100 }}
                >
                  ElementID: {element.id}
                  <br />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`useRef` is basically the same as doing `useState({ current: <value you pass in> })`;

Given your use case, what you have done is sufficient however I would change use ref to initialise with an object since that is what you are actually using as oppose to an array:

```
const itemsRef = useRef({});
```

Your code still works but may potentially give you some unexpected behaviour since assigning properties to an array can be a bit weird and is definitely not what you intend to do anyway.

For example with an array you are actually doing this:

```
[]["<some id>"] = el; // very weird!
```

vs an object:

```
{}["<some id>"] = el
```

Comment: `useRef` is nothing like `useState`, the second cause re-render while first not

Comment: @HagaiHarari Actually no. If you used useState and then did items.current = <value> it will not cause a re-render. I did not say it is exactly the same as useState anyway... https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1099842565631819776

Comment: Hi Dylan thanks for the answer. The only issue I am currently facing is that `itemsRef.current[element.id]` seems to cause issues. Once I console.log(itemsRef), it returns current: Array[0] however in this example here it returns current: Array[3]. The difference is [element.id] vs [i]. However, I can't use `i` in my case as it is a loop inside a loop.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kalam-6mikt?file=/src/App.js:342-364

Comment: @JoeyCoder These are two different use cases. The one in your OP has id's but this one is an array. Have you considered instead using an object and mapping like this .current[item] = el

Comment: Okay I see. Maybe I don't understand completely how `itemsRef ` works. I expected it to be filled with all the references and wasn't sure if it actually works properly as it just says `current: Array[0]` The `const blueprint` is coming through an API call. I will also attach a simplified version in the comments below to show my confusion.

Comment: `current: Array[3]` (as expected)
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kalam-6mikt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `current: Array[0]` (Why? Isn't it supposed to be filled with two refs (condition.id))
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-platform-95qim?file=/src/App.js:638-655

Comment: @HagaiHarari Actually, both useRef and useState causes re-render, the difference is that updating a useRef value causes a shallow re-render, while updating a useState causes a deep re-render. Shallow re-render only affects the component. Deep re-render affects the component and all of its children.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right approach, usually, you will see `useRef([])` when handling multiple  animations in a page, and that's exactly how it's done `itemsRef.current[element.id] = el`.

> My main concern now is if that's the right and performance efficient approach

That's directly related to ["Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil"](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPremature%20optimization%20is%20the%20root,The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%3A&text=This%20original%20quote%20about%20premature,time%20ago%20in%20the%201960s.).

> Premature optimization is spending a lot of time on something that you may not actually need.

You trying to optimize before you have any performance issues. Focus on delivering the product and clean code, find a time for optimization when you actually measured it.

> We also don’t want to waste an enormous amount of time doing performance optimization on things that don’t matter. Many development teams get caught up in focusing on optimizing for performance and scale before they have validated their new product functionality.